# Treeview Control Expand

Tags: c#, treeview

I am using a treeview control in C# .net 3.5. When i expand the root node the children of the root node are also getting expanded. What i want is when i expand the root node on the children of root node to be show without they being expanded.

Comment: can you share some of your expansion code ? Would help us know if you're doing winforms or wpf and what you are doing.

Comment: The problem is solved.I am adding nodes dynamically when a node is expanded. I used Tree Node.Expanded = False; whenever i add a new node.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding child nodes dynamically when any given node is expanded, you just need to set the `node.Expanded` property to `false` for each child node that you add.

That should solve your problem.